# how to conditionally stop an observable's timed interval sequence?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, observable, system.reactive, intervals

Here's the code that runs every second to output a number in sequence:

```
IObservable<DateTimeOffset> timestamps =
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Timestamp()
    .Where(x => x.Value % 2 == 0)
    .Select(x => x.Timestamp);
timestamps.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

It works. My question is, I wish that the Observable will generate this timestamps and stop when some condition met, like

```
if (x==100) then stop
```

Is there a way to achieve this via Rx/Linq?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stop" is the notification `OnComplete`. "Throw" is the notification `OnError`.
There are operators available to push both types of notifications.

You can also use the `TakeWhile` operator, which is also available in `IEnumerable`, and they behave very much the same.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01))
.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
.TakeWhile(x => x != 100)
.Timestamp()
.Select(x => x.Timestamp);
```

For notifications which are asynchronous with your stream there are the `...Until` operators like `TakeUntil`, `SkipUntil`.
For example, to *stop* the observable after 100 seconds.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01))
.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)))
.Timestamp()
.Select(x => x.Timestamp);
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!